# Flash CS6 - how to replace a playing card index (i.e. how to type into same bounding box)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, adobe-flash, cs6, cs5

I've purchased [a stock set of playing cards in .ai format](http://graphicriver.net/item/set-of-52-playing-cards-for-online-gaming/2989479) and have successfully imported it into a Flash CS6 file.

However I have the problem, that the cards have english indices: J, Q, K, A - while I need russian letters instead.

I've spent many hours trying to replace the indices (using Text tool and "Break apart" command), however the results do not look good.

Main reason being, that I don't know, which font was used originally (something bold and condensed).

So my question is: when I select the index graphic to be replaced (like shown in the screenshot below) - is there a way in Flash CS6 to type a new character into the same bounding box?

I think this would ensure a pretty similar looking russian letter - almost regardless of the font I take:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to what I understand from your question, the Illustrator file has the letters in curves or outlines, and not in text. This means all information about the font has been lost, and you only have a "drawing" of the letters. So it won't let you edit them.

If this is the case, you will need to re-add a text layer in Illustrator, with the russian characters, on top of the original one (and delete the old one).

You can do this very easily. Use some guides to remember where the letter is supposed to go. Then hide/delete the old letter and just use the `Type Tool` to create a new text object in the same place. Choose a similar font, size and weight, and when you are done (this is very important, but make sure you are not making other further changes as this is more or less irreversible), right click on the text and choose `Create Outlines`.

You will need the letters in outlines to work with them in flash.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't there a way to constrict my typing to the "black box" when typing in Flash CS6 instead? I'm asking because I have no experience with AI, thus using it is very difficult for me.

Also, will "Create outlines" turn the text into a "shape" in AI (that would be good for my Flash game, don't need text labels there - since they are misplaced for some reason, when I rotate cards).

Comment: I think the black box is just the size of the drawing, nothing else. If flash lets you delete it, then it'd be the same, you can add the new text in flash, and convert to outlines.

Comment: You can select the character, then click the font size and use the up and down arrows until the new letter is the same size as the old letter. I think if you just make it static text, it will embed and allow you to rotate it. You can also break the text apart in Flash (since you have already done the work to import the graphics).

Comment: You can also click the color swatch on one or both of the layers to make them outlines. That is sometimes helpful.